# Save a MapControl map to an MXD

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine, mxd

I used to know how to do this, but I must have lost the code.  I tried this:

```
IMxdContents mxdcontents = mapControl.Map as IMxdContents;
IMapDocument doc = new MapDocumentClass();
doc.ReplaceContents(mxdcontents);
doc.SaveAs("C:\\test.mxd");
```

But I got a "data is not ready to complete operation".

How can I save my ArcEngine mapcontrol map as an .mxd?

Comment: did you try just setting IMxdContents mxdcontents = mapControl ?

Comment: @Kirk Kuykendall I just tried that it resolved to null

Comment: what happens if you don't use `as`, but instead use `mxdcontents = (IMxdContents)mapControl` ?  Also, call `doc.New("test.mxd")` before `ReplaceContents`.

Comment: If you are just saving what you already loaded then:

    IMapDocument mapDocument = new MapDocumentClass();
    mapDocument.Save( true, false );

should work?! (Does for me.)

Comment: @Chaz I get a "Data necessary to complete op is not avail" using that code. :(

Comment: Have you opened a map document to load that mapControl? Have you looked at "How to synchronize the MapControl and PageLayoutControl" in the docs?  Have you tried the IActiveView.Activate method?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do New or Open on the IMapDocument before ReplaceContent is called see the sample for [SaveLayerFileCmd](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/0001/0001000007wq000000.htm).

Answer (score 1):

```
public void saveMap()
{
    IMapDocument mapDocument = new MapDocumentClass();
    mapDocument.Open(@"[path to your .mxd]", string.Empty);
    if (mapDocument.get_IsReadOnly(@"[path to your .mxd]"))
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Map document \"" + @"[path to your .mxd]" + "\" is read only!");
        mapDocument.Close();
        return;
    }
    mapDocument.ReplaceContents((IMxdContents)m_mapControl.Map);
    mapDocument.Save(mapDocument.UsesRelativePaths, true);
    mapDocument.Close();
}
```